# Вывести строку, в которой имеется PHP код

Tags: php, html

Имеется, к примеру, такой код:

```
$items = [...];

//И строка, в которой имеется php код
$code = "<ul><? foreach($items as $item): ?><li><?=$item['name']?></li><? endforeach; ?></ul>";

echo $code;
```

Возможно ли перед выводом на экран, выполнить PHP код, находящийся в строке?

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл! Всё в одну строку делается:
`eval(' ?>'.$code.'<?php ');`